# Loop not going further

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm pretty new to VBA and programming in general.
This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a database starting on row 21 of my worksheet (storing a name, second name, job). I'm trying to use a for loop, to create a new worksheet for every name in the database - for example (1 - William), (2 - John) ...

When we add a new member to our database and run our macro - It should add the a new sheet (but don't change anything to the existing ones), so with other words just skip (1 - William) and (2 - John) but adds (3 - Kera).

So far it's creating the 2 first worksheets, but when I add someone to my database - the new worksheet isn't added.

Could any of you experts help me with this issue, and brake down what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

Dim blnFound As Boolean
blnFound = False

For i = 21 To LastRow

For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(x).Name = ((i -21) + 1) & " - " & Worksheets("Database").Cells(i, 3).Value Then
        blnFound = True
    End If
Next

    If blnFound = False Then
        Worksheets.Add.Move After:=Sheets(1)
        ActiveSheet.Name = ((i - 21) + 1) & " - " & Worksheets("Database").Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you this will help you:

```
Sub CreateNewSheetFromRange()

    Dim mySht As Worksheet
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim BeginRow As Long
    Dim myStr As String

    Dim r As New Collection
    Dim Pos As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For a = 1 To Sheets.Count

        'To List Your Sheet With Name Begin With Number & " - "
        'If you don't care how many time time the same value repeat,
        'you can disobey this for loop
        Pos = InStr(Sheets(a).Name, " - ")
        If Pos > 0 Then
           r.Add Sheets(a).Name, Mid(Sheets(a).Name, Pos + 3)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next


    BeginRow = 21

    Do While True
       On Error Resume Next
       myStr = ((BeginRow - 21) + 1) & " - " & Worksheets("Data").Cells(BeginRow, 3).Value

       If Worksheets("Data").Cells(BeginRow, 3).Value = "" Then
          Exit Do
       End If

       'If you hope avoid your repeated cells value to create new sheet
       'perform this
       myVal = r.Item(Worksheets("Data").Cells(BeginRow, 3).Value)
       'If you don't care about repeated value, you change this with:
       'set mySht=worksheets(myStr)

       If Err.Description <> "" Then
          On Error GoTo 0
          Set mySheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
          'If you don't care about repeated value, remove this r.add
           r.Add myStr, Worksheets("Data").Cells(BeginRow, 3).Value
          mySheet.Name = myStr
          a = 1
       End If

       BeginRow = BeginRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I give OP the option, the first from data cell begin from A21 to last row, as a view of thought, but the second, is to perform OP purpose, from C21 until empty cell of column C. The difficulty is because the OP give the name with prefix number & " - ", so I store all sheet with prefix something & " - " to collection. From cells value gotten, I checked if the sheets existing, if no I create new sheet with name as defined by OP, row-21+1 & " - " & cells value, and add this to collection.